# compiler reordering and load operation

Tags: c++, atomic

I'm starting lock free programming and I encounter some difficulties for basic stuff. I have found the following example :

```
#define COMPILER_BARRIER() asm volatile("" ::: "memory")

int Value;
int IsPublished = 0;

void sendValue(int x)
{
    Value = x;
    COMPILER_BARRIER();          // prevent reordering of stores
    IsPublished = 1;
}

int tryRecvValue()
{
    if (IsPublished)
    {
        COMPILER_BARRIER();      // prevent reordering of loads
        return Value;
    }
    return -1;  // or some other value to mean not yet received
}
```

What kind of reordering a compiler can perform in `tryRecvValue`  function ?

Comment: Just in case you've missed it: C++11 [standartized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order) the stuff, so one doesn't need to use asm (theoretically)

Comment: `COMPILER_BARRIER()` will act as a read+write barrier to the compiler.  To be clear: it will have NO effect on CPU out-of-order execution.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

Without the inline asm*, the compiler is able to load the value from `Value` first, then `IsPublished`, then perform the check and return.

*Always check the assembly output if you're not sure what the compiler is doing. This is especially true of lock free programming techniques.*

## More Information

* NOTE: Inline asm is not a required part of the C++ standard, but is implemented by all major compilers. It is only mentioned in section 7.4:

> The asm declaration is conditionally-supported; its meaning is implementation-defined. [ Note: Typically it
>   is used to pass information through the implementation to an assembler. — end note ]

Generally speaking, compilers cannot reorder reads and writes around inline assembly because the compiler cannot make assumptions about what the assembly does.

The use of `COMPILER_BARRIER()` above will not act as any kind of read/write barrier, it just has the side affect of not allowing reordering of assembly instructions around the statement.

Assuming the above code is called from different threads, it will only work as-is on x86, since the architecture guarantees that writes are never (observably) reordered by the cpu. (reference: 8.2.3.2 in volume 3A of the [Intel Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html))

For use on other architectures with relaxed memory models, (like PowerPc and ARM) you'll need hardware barriers that prevent these types of reorders. For a good breakdown, check out [Jeff Preshing's articles](http://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/).